# Using pointers to access 2D array in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on a code to access elements of an array using Depth-First Search. If I come across a 'Y', I replace it with a '*' and increment my count. But while using pointers, I am encountering the following error:

```
In function 'dfs':
5:5: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')


In function 'checkMe':
23:16: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

Here is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dfs(char* m,int r,int c,int v1,int v2)
{
    *(*(m+r)+c) = '*';
    for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        if((r<(v1-1))&&(c<(v2-1)))
        {
            dfs(m,r,c,v1,v2);
        }
    }
} 

int checkMe(char* m,int row,int col)
{
    int counter = 0,i=0,j=0;

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            if(*(*(m+i)+j) == 'Y')
            {
                dfs(m,i,j,row,col);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0,count = 0,p = 4,q = 4;
    char input[4][4]={{'Y','Y','Y','N'},{'N','N','N','Y'},{'Y','Y','N','Y'},{'Y','N','N','N'}};

    count = checkMe(input,p,q);
    printf("%d",count);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You incorrectly defined parameters of the functions. For example instead of char* m funsction checkMe shall have parameter type either char m[][4] or char ( *m )[4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the first parameter of the functions incorrectly. For example function `checkMe` must be defined like

```
int checkMe(char m[][4], int row, int col )
{
    int counter = 0,i=0,j=0;

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            if(*(*(m+i)+j) == 'Y')
            {
                dfs(m,i,j,row,col);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

An equivalent declaration of the first parameter is also the following

```
char ( *m )[4]
```

In fact it is enough to have only two parameters because the number of columns is known. Or if your compiler supports variable length arrays then you could declare the function like

```
int checkMe( int row, int col, char m[][col] );
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change `*(*(m+r)+c) = '*'`  to `*((*m+r)+c)`. Since `m` is a `char` pointer. You have to use the value pointing by it.